# Hibernate lock table before update

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have two REST APIs that modifies values in two different rows of the same table.

Both APIs are sometimes called simultaneously. The problem is that when the second API finish modifying the table, It would have overwritten any changes made by the first API.

The table is `Contact` with rows like the below:

```
         Name | Email    |Phone
Admin    x    | x@y.com  | 123
Tech.    y    | y@x.com  | 456
```

When both the APIs finish, I end up with a table like below:

```
         Name | Email      |Phone
Admin    xNew | xNew@y.com | 123
Tech.    y    | y@x.com    | 456
```

**OR sometimes**

```
         Name | Email      |Phone
Admin    x    | x@y.com    | 123
Tech.    yNew | yNew@x.com | 456
```

**I lose either one of the updates**

I have to provide separate APIs to update Admin. and Tech. contacts. (If it was a single API, issue will not be there)

For now I have solved the issue by synchronizing (Java) the call to the method which reads and updates the values in the object (and to the DB table)

the pseudo code for the Method which does the update is:

```
void saveContactData(adminContact, techContact, orgID){
    Organzation org = getOrgDao().findByID(orgID);
    if (adminContact != null)
       org.setAdmin(contact);
    else if (techContact != null)
       org.setTech(contact);
    getOrgDao().saveorUpdate(org);
}
```

But I feel there should be something available in Hibernate to take care of this. I explored **HibernateLockStrategy**, but it seems to lock a single record and not the full table.

The HBM mappings are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT" schema="public" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">contact_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="CONTACT_NAME"/>
        <property name="email" type="string" column="EMAIL"/>
        <property name="phone" type="string" column="PHONE"/>
        <property name="cellPhone" type="string" column="CELL_PHONE"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And in the organization dao:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "admin")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Contact admin;
@JoinColumn(name = "tech")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Contact tech;
```

Note:

1. The DB is **postgres**
2. I'm a hibernate n00b

Comment: You've left out your code, which is rather relevant here.

Comment: Do you create your Hibernate session in your REST service implementation?

Comment: "*that modifies values in two different rows of the same table*" - if you have a proper primary key for the table, then two concurrent updates to **different** rows are no problem at all.

Comment: @MareGeldenhuys, no, I don't explicitly create any session.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The contact object is aggregated in the Organization object. There is no separate DAO for contact table.

Comment: @CraigRinger added the code. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to teach your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") to **not** update entities that have not been changed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please elaborate? I didn't understand that. As I told, I'm new to the inner-workings of hibernate.

Comment: Have you considered Optimistic Locking?

Comment: @MareGeldenhuys I do get a stale state exception with some variations of the code, Somebody told me that, Optimistic locking is by default enabled. But this issue looks more like a side effect of either a bad design or programming error to me, only the later is under my control, so I'm just searching for a way to circumvent this without much overhead.

Comment: @gkns so you do have a <version> column on Organization then, as well as on Contact?

Comment: @MareGeldenhuys No both the tables don't have any version column

Comment: @gkns in most cases for optimistic locking to work, you would need to have version columns on the actual tables and defined in your entities. Can you edit the post and add the entity class and hbm files?

Comment: @MareGeldenhuys added.